# Gradle Kotlin project dependentbot not upgrading or raising PR for new versions

Tags: kotlin, gradle, dependabot

I have a Gradle Kotlin project where I define dependencies using an object for versioning, like so:

```
object Versions {
const val MICROMETER = "1.11.5"
}
dependencies {
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-core:${Versions.MICROMETER}")
}
```

I've noticed that the dependent bot doesn't automatically upgrade or raise a pull request to update to the new version when a new version of the dependency is available. Interestingly, when I simplify the setup without using the object for versioning, as shown below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.11.5")
}
```

The dependent bot does raise a pull request for upgrading to the new version.

Is there a specific configuration or setting I'm missing in my Gradle Kotlin project that would enable the dependentbot to automatically upgrade dependencies when using an object for versioning?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can use [version catalogs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:conventional-dependencies-toml).
Create a `libs.versions.toml` file in your `gradle` folder (where the gradle wrapper files are). And declare your versions and dependencies in that file.

```ini
[versions]
micrometer = "1.11.5"

[libraries]
micrometer-core = { module = "io.micrometer:micrometer-core", version.ref = "micrometer " }
```

And use it like this

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.micrometer.core)
}
```

Comment: What if we have multi module project, will it gonna work?

Comment: Yes, version catalogs work in multi-module projects.